# Sentence to Image

Tags: computational-linguistics, sentences

Does anyone know of a database or tool that can be used to produce or find images that help describe or reinforce the meaning of a given sentence?

For example:

"The car was going very fast."

[image: The car was going too fast]

I am producing exercises for my language students and I would like to complement the sentences involved with visual cues. Google Images is useful but I'm interested in exploring alternatives.

Comment: I think this question is not about Linguistics. It may better fit at [scicomp.se], however: [here's](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/28173/) a recent similar question there, but please double-check if it is on-topic there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about the languages itself.

Comment: Automated image description is a topic in Copmutational Linguistics (altho' a marginal one), therefore I vote to leave this question open here.